# Linking at Compile Time vs Linking at Runtime Against std:: library

Tags: linux, qt, makefile, libstdc++

First the question:
I need a way without placing a config file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d to allow clients to build against my SDK on both RHEL5.7 and RHEL6.1 using the default install of gcc. Setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not work in this case. Are there any other ways to allow clients to link against my sdk without having to provide them with a knowledge base article on how to configure their system? Please read below for clarification.

Second the senario:

I am responsible for the build of a runtime SDK on both RHEL5 and RHEL6. My RHEL5.7 box is a standard non-registered install as is my RHEL6.1 box. However, on my RHEL6 box I have compiled gcc myself:

```
[mehoggan@hoggant35002 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release; gcc --version
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 (Tikanga)
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOS
```

--

```
[mehoggan@hogganz400 session2]$ cat /etc/redhat-release; gcc --version
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.1 (Santiago)
gcc (GCC) 4.5.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

--

I cannot provide the .so and .a files I am trying to link against. However, I will attempt to depict what is happening. Taking the same source and building it against my SDK and running it. I get the following results:

RHEL 6 Box:

```
[mehoggan@hogganz400 session2]$ ls -l
total 1848
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mehoggan mehoggan     189 Nov  3 13:02 main.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mehoggan mehoggan     845 Nov  3 13:02 mainwindow.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mehoggan mehoggan     288 Nov  3 13:02 mainwindow.h
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mehoggan mehoggan   25818 Nov  4 09:26 Session2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mehoggan mehoggan     649 Nov  3 13:02 Session2.pro
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mehoggan mehoggan 1847296 Nov  3 13:02 vc90.pdb
[mehoggan@hogganz400 session2]$ qmake
[mehoggan@hogganz400 session2]$ cat Session2.pro 
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2011-10-21T09:32:55
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT += core gui

TARGET = Session2
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

#Modify the path accordingly
CONFIG += debug_and_release
INCLUDEPATH += "/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/include"
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
  LIBS += -L"/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/bin" \
          -lArcGISQtd
} else {
  LIBS += -L"/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/bin" \
          -lArcGISQt
}
[mehoggan@hogganz400 session2]$ make
make -f Makefile.Release
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/workshops/session2'
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/default -I. -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtCore -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtGui -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include -I../../include -Irelease -o release/main.o main.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/default -I. -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtCore -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtGui -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include -I../../include -Irelease -o release/mainwindow.o mainwindow.cpp
/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/bin/moc -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/default -I. -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtCore -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtGui -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include -I../../include -Irelease mainwindow.h -o release/moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/default -I. -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtCore -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtGui -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include -I../../include -Irelease -o release/moc_mainwindow.o release/moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib -o Session2 release/main.o release/mainwindow.o release/moc_mainwindow.o    -L/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib -L/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/bin -lArcGISQt -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/workshops/session2'
[mehoggan@hogganz400 session2]$ echo ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} 
/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/ArcGISRuntime10.1/LocalServerLx/bin/wine/lib64:/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/ArcGISRuntime10.1/LocalServerLx/bin/wine/lib64/wine:/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/ArcGISRuntime10.1/LocalServerLx/bin/wine/lib64/wine/supp:/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/ArcGISRuntime10.1/LocalServerLx/bin/wine/lib64:/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/ArcGISRuntime10.1/LocalServerLx/bin/wine/lib64/wine:/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/ArcGISRuntime10.1/LocalServerLx/bin/wine/lib64/wine/supp:
[mehoggan@hogganz400 session2]$ ./Session2 
./Session2: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by /home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/bin/libArcGISQt.so.1)
```

If I run the following command: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}; ./Session2` or set the path to the compiled version of libstdc++ in /etc/ld.so.conf.d the application runs.

RHEL5 Box:

```
[mehoggan@hoggant35002 session2]$ ls -l
total 1852
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mehoggan mehoggan     189 Nov  3 15:21 main.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mehoggan mehoggan     845 Nov  3 15:21 mainwindow.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mehoggan mehoggan     288 Nov  3 15:21 mainwindow.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mehoggan mehoggan     649 Nov  3 15:21 Session2.pro
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mehoggan mehoggan   25151 Nov  3 15:51 Session2.pro.user
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mehoggan mehoggan 1847296 Nov  3 15:21 vc90.pdb
[mehoggan@hoggant35002 session2]$ qmake
[mehoggan@hoggant35002 session2]$ ls -l ./Session2.pro
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mehoggan mehoggan 649 Nov  3 15:21 ./Session2.pro
[mehoggan@hoggant35002 session2]$ cat ./Session2.pro
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2011-10-21T09:32:55
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT += core gui

TARGET = Session2
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

#Modify the path accordingly
CONFIG += debug_and_release
INCLUDEPATH += "/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/include"
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
  LIBS += -L"/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/bin" \
          -lArcGISQtd
} else {
  LIBS += -L"/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/bin" \
          -lArcGISQt
}
[mehoggan@hoggant35002 session2]$ make
make -f Makefile.Release
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/workshops/session2'
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/default -I. -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtCore -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtGui -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include -I../../include -Irelease -o release/main.o main.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/default -I. -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtCore -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtGui -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include -I../../include -Irelease -o release/mainwindow.o mainwindow.cpp
/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/bin/moc -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/default -I. -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtCore -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtGui -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include -I../../include -Irelease mainwindow.h -o release/moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/default -I. -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtCore -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtGui -I/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include -I../../include -Irelease -o release/moc_mainwindow.o release/moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib -o Session2 release/main.o release/mainwindow.o release/moc_mainwindow.o    -L/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib -L/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/bin -lArcGISQt -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread
/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined reference to `FT_Library_SetLcdFilter'
/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/bin/libArcGISQt.so: undefined reference to `std::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()@GLIBCXX_3.4.14'
/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/bin/libArcGISQt.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.9'
/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/bin/libArcGISQt.so: undefined reference to `std::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::_List_node_base*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.14'
/home/mehoggan/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined reference to `FcFreeTypeQueryFace'
/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/bin/libArcGISQt.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_insert<double>(double)@GLIBCXX_3.4.9'
/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/bin/libArcGISQt.so: undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const@GLIBCXX_3.4.11'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Session2] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mehoggan/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt10.1/SDK/workshops/session2'
make: *** [release] Error 2
```

This is getting to be a really long post, and I think I have provided enough to start helping. Please let me know if you need anything specific to help.

One last bit of information on the libstdc++ I am linking against.

```
RHEL6:
[mehoggan@hogganz400 session2]$ strings /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIB
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

RHEL5:

```
[mehoggan@hoggant35002 session2]$ strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your Qt libraries (libQtGui.so and libArcGISQt.so) have a dependency on GLIBCXX_3.4.14, which is not present on your RHEL 5 box, probably as you built and installed it (Qt) on your RHEL 6 box.  You need to build Qt on RHEL 5, or provide access to the updated 3.4.14 lib on the RHEL 5 box.  Anyone who wants to run your binary will need access to the correct versions of the shared libraries it was built against.

In order to have 'access' to a library, it needs to be readable on the machine in question and be in a location that is either configured in ld.so.conf, in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH envvar at the app is run, OR configured into the executable via a -rpath link option.

One linking option I find EXTREMELY useful for avoiding/dealing with this issue is `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'`.  This will cause the application to look in the directory containing the executable for dynamic libs as well as (and in preference to) ld.so.conf.  So you can build an executable and give people a package with the executable and a bunch of .so dynamic libs and tell them "either install the .so files on your machine or stick them all in the same directory as the executable, whichever you prefer" and then they can run the executable without too much trouble.  This allows for a single binary package that can be used on pretty much any linux variant.

Note that when you put this option in a Makefile it generally needs to be `-Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN'` as make will treat the `$` as a variable expansion (`$$` expands to `$`).  qmake may be the same.